# customizing css in the box

Tags: css

I have `tag me` box to add the tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/hailwood/u8zj5/

I was trying to change it's looks using css.

I wanted to create tags and box to look like in this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hAz5A/20/

I added the css in first but does not make change. Can any css guys help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the css from the second fiddle into the first fiddle

Note: if you want to remove the 'x' - delete tag (for some reason) then add `display: none` to your tagit-close class

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/u8zj5/212/)

[FIDDLE without delete button](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/u8zj5/213/)

```
   ul.tagit.ui-widget li.tagit-choice {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        line-height: inherit;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: #EFEFEF;
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: #08c;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.tagit.ui-widget li.tagit-choice a.tagit-close {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -8px;
    }
```

Comment: thanks a ton. Can you please tell me how can I fix the width of `input`? Currently it keept expanding horizontaly as user keep entering tags. And also where the css to change the box same?

Comment: @Danield: Hey nice one, how each tag could be store or fetched? like to store into database?